# Does it really matter how much you allocate to the MySQL Column?

Tags: mysql, database

```
String(255) vs String(99999)
```

When designing MySQL Columns, Does it really matter? I mean...I have tons of hard drive space.

Comment: Your 'tons of hard drive space' will suddenly not seem so big as the number of rows in your table grows by orders of magnitude.

Comment: see: http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/424/performance-implications-of-mysql-varchar-sizes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, it's not just a matter of how much disk space you have.. but it's a matter of the table's restrictions/limitations as well:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/table-size-limit.html

Answer (score 0):

mysql saves the long text fields as varchar when they are short and the engine carries them to off-table storage if the data is updated to longer size. so it doesn't matter.

if you use big sizes you can't use standard index on your varchar field and you will have to use full text index. myisam supports full text index whereas innodb doesn't